# Python sorting numerically in text file

Tags: python

Hi I'm working on a mini game that store user's time taken to complete the game as their score. I'm able to append the scores into my text file but I failed to sort them.

example:
17.25 jason
18.5  simon
20.12 ben

```
def scoring():
    #appending level 1 score
    L1=[]
    L1.append((Timetaken,myname))
    with open('L1.txt','a') as x:
        x.write('%f,%s'%(Timetaken,myname))
def arranging():
    #Sorting level 1
    column=[]
    with open('L1.txt') as file1:
        for line in file1:
            column.append(line.split('\n'))
    sorted(column,key=itemgetter(0),reverse=False)
    with open("L1.txt",'w+') as first:
        for x in column:
            if (len(column))<=10:
            first.write(str(x)+str(' , '))`
```

Comment: You will get more and better answers if you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.  Especially make sure that the input and expected test data are complete (not pseudo-data), and can be easily cut and and paste into an editor to allow testing proposed solutions.

Comment: what is `Timetaken`? please show an https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Timetaken is the score of the player

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that sorted() doesn't sort in place. You need to do:

```
column = sorted(column,key=itemgetter(0),reverse=False)
```